# BeautifulSoup CSS selector working enclosed with '', but not when enclosed with ""

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I have found CSS selector that is working when enclosed in `''`, but not working when enclosed with `""`.

*If anybody knows why, I would love to know.*

First I was thinking that I must use `''`, but in [official documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `""` is used.

Only conclusion that I see is because on original page links are in `""`, but I have filing that it is not a reason.

Here is source code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features="lxml")

# get all countries with links to holidays
links = soup.select('li > a[href*="/holidays/"]')    # WORKING
# links = soup.select("li > a[href*='/holidays/']")  # NOT WORKING

for item in links:
    print item

print len(links)
```

Comment: You appear to have your quotes *confused*. The code is working with double quotes, not working with single. But your question is stating the *opposite*.

Comment: But in testing, I found the *opposite* is true. `"/holidays/"` works, `'/holidays/'` does not. Incidentally, not using quotes at all also works.

Comment: The CSS syntax parser used is rather simplistic; that it works without quotes and not with single quotes is certainly not conformant with the CSS specs.

Comment: Note that other valid CSS selectors also don't work in BeautifulSoup; you cannot combine multiple types of selectors either. That's fine, BeautifulSoup never aimed to give you a fully compliant CSS parser anyway, the `.select()` method is more meant as a convenience.

Comment: Are you asking about the quotes in the *CSS selector*, or the quotes around the Python string here? Are you confusing `'...'` around the selector with the `"..."` *in the string value that is the selector*?

Comment: I am confused why one is working and another is not.

Comment: And I am confused as to what quotes you are talking about. You keep mixing them up.

Comment: all quotes together, this is working `'li > a[href*="/holidays/"]'`, this is not working ``"li > a[href*='/holidays/']". And to add to confusion, you said it, and I have verify it, without quotes around `/holidays/` everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the CSS selector syntax requires double quotes for its internal quoting. Thus why a string with the *value* `li > a[href*='/holidays/']` wouldn't work, while a string with the *value* `li > a[href*="/holidays/"]` would. To create strings with the latter value in Python, you could use either single or double quotes (since in Python there is no difference between the two, as there is in Perl). However, if you used double quotes to enclose the string, you would have to escape the double quotes embedded in it, like so:

```
soup.select("li > a[href*=\"/holidays/\"]")
```

This is a bit cumbersome compared to just using the single quotes, so that would be a cleaner solution here.

Comment: Note that you are saying the **exact opposite** of what the OP is claiming. I'm not sure why you feel the need to explain about using double quotes in a string, since the OP has clearly already learned to use single quotes in that case. And there is also the *triple quote* option you missed.

Comment: The requirement of double quotes for the CSS-selector-internal quoting is consistent both with the docs and with testing I just carried out. It also matches the code OP actually posted.

Comment: I agree that double quotes work, single quotes don't. The OP is saying the *opposite* of that. *I have found CSS selector that is working when enclosed in `''`, but not working when enclosed with `""`.*

Comment: True. I suspect that this is a confusion between the internal quotes which are passed to BeautifulSoup (which need to be double) and the quotes which Python uses to create that literal (which can be single or double, or triple for that matter, but single is easiest). The CSS selector could be said to be 'enclosed' in either.

Comment: Perhaps; that's a good point. But the OP included samples with `# WORKING` and `# NOT WORKING` in their question that are patently the opposite of what their question is asking about.

Comment: Were those edited afterward? What I see at the moment is wholly consistent with the testing I did: the one with internal double quotes works, the one with internal single quotes doesn't.

Comment: No, those have been there all along. Again, the OP is stating the opposite of what is actually happening. I've voted to close the question as there is no way we can reproduce what the OP is claiming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71347/discussion-between-tom-hunt-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: No, lets not. I already spent too much energy on this question. :-) Sorry!